# Regular expression to check file in bash

Tags: regex, file, bash

Is it possible to check whether a file exists with regular expression in bash?

I tried as follows:

```
if [ -f /path/to/file*.txt ]
```

But unfortunately this does not work.

Does anyone know how this is possible?

Comment: -e is work, -f does not work.

Comment: As a regular expression, "file*.txt" will match "fil.txt", and "fileeee.txt", but not "filefoo.txt".  A glob is not a regular expression.

Comment: Hm, interesing. I will try. Thanks.

Comment: QQ..is there one file in that directory or there is a possibility of more than one file?

Answer (score 5):

Your approach would work as long as there is exactly one file that matches the pattern. bash expands the wildcard first, resulting in a call like:

```
if [ -f /path/to/file*.txt ]
if [ -f /path/to/file1.txt ]
if [ -f /path/to/file1.txt /path/to/file2.txt ]
```

depending on the number of matches (0, 1, 2, respectively). To check just for the existence, you might just use find:

```
find /path/to -name 'file*.txt' | grep -q '.'
```

Answer (score 0):

As @thiton explains the [`glob` (not a real regexp)](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html) is expanded and the check fails when multiple files exists matching the glob.

You can exploit instead `compgen` as explained here
[Test whether a glob has any matches in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937407/test-whether-a-glob-has-any-matches-in-bash)
[Read more on the man page of `compgen`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion-Builtins.html)

Here is an example

```
if $(compgen -G "/path/to/file*.txt" > /dev/null); then
    echo "Some files exist."
fi
```