# Check if at least one file exists in bash

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I have this

```
if [[ -e file.jpg ]] ;then echo "aaaaaaaaa"; fi
```

and it prints "aaaaaaa"

but I want to print if there is file.png or file.png also

so I need something like this

```
if [[ -e file.* ]] ;then echo "aaaaaaaaa"; fi
```

but it doesn't work I am missing something in the syntax

Thanks

Comment: "at list" or "at least"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Test whether a glob has any matches in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937407/test-whether-a-glob-has-any-matches-in-bash)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use a loop ?

```
for i in file.*; do
   if [[ -e $i ]]; then
      # exists...
   fi
done
```

Answer (score 10):

If you enable bash's `nullglob` setting, the pattern file.* will expand to an empty string if there are no such files:

```
shopt -s nullglob
files=(file.*)
# now check the size of the array
if (( ${#files[@]} == 0 )); then
    echo "no such files"
else
    echo "at least one:"
    printf "aaaaaaaaa %s\n" "${files[@]}"
fi
```

If you do not enable nullglob, then `files=(file.*)` will result in an array with one element, the string "file.*"