# Building a csv file from multiple files

Tags: bash, csv

I have on a folder multiple txt file containing one or several lines. Each file name is an email address containing different email(s) address(es) inside.

For example, I have 3 files on my folder :

- distribution-list1@example.com.txt
- distribution-list2@example.com.txt
- distribution-list3@example.com.txt

Content of each files:

```
cat distribution-list1@example.com.txt
john@example.com
aurel@example.com

cat distribution-list2@example.com.txt
doe@example.com

cat distribution-list3@example.com.txt
jack@example.com
gilbert@example.com
jane@example.com
```

I would like to build only one file containing those data:

```
distribution-list1@example.com;john@example.com
distribution-list1@example.com;aurel@example.com
distribution-list2@example.com;doe@example.com
distribution-list3@example.com;jack@example.com
distribution-list3@example.com;gilbert@example.com
distribution-list3@example.com;jane@example.com
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Looping through the content of a file in Bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521462/looping-through-the-content-of-a-file-in-bash)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**lists_merge.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s nullglob;
for fname in *.txt;
do
  while read line; 
  do
    printf "%s;%s\n" "$fname" "$line";
  done <"$fname";
done;
```

**output**

```
$ ./lists_merge.sh 
distribution-list1@example.com.txt;john@example.com
distribution-list1@example.com.txt;aurel@example.com
distribution-list2@example.com.txt;doe@example.com
distribution-list3@example.com.txt;jack@example.com
distribution-list3@example.com.txt;gilbert@example.com
distribution-list3@example.com.txt;jane@example.com
```

> note: script assumed to be in same directory as distribution list text
>   files. assumed no other text files are in this directory

---

**reference**

**[nullglob info](http://bash.cumulonim.biz/NullGlob.html)**

Comment: Why did you use the line ``shopt -s nullglob;``?

Comment: this is to handle the case that there are no *.txt matches for the glob. in this case bash would throw an error without the nullglob option. see also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937407/test-whether-a-glob-has-any-matches-in-bash)

Comment: You can safely remove all the semicolons from your script - they are only needed when you put two separate statements on one line.

Comment: yes, they are optional. my style preference is to include them ( feels closer to other languages i use ). from an error-rate perspective though always having semicolons after while loop statements helps even if i dont have a newline before the do statement

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sed`:

```
for emailfile in *.txt; do
    email=${emailfile%.txt}
    sed "s:^:$email;:" "$emailfile"
done
```

This will fail if an email ID has a colon (`:`), but I doubt you'd have such an example.