# Check if files of a given type exist in bash shell

Tags: bash, shell, unix, automator

I want to use Automator in my Mac with the shell to tidy up my files. I try to write some command like this:

```
mv -f /Users/myname/Downloads/*.zip /Users/myname/Downloads/zip/
mv -f /Users/myname/Downloads/*.txt /Users/myname/Downloads/txt/
```

and they worked. But I found that 'mv' will return error if no file matches, so I want to make something like this.

```
if (txt file) , mv *.txt /txt/
if (zip file) , mv *.txt /zip/
```

I found that the if statement is using

```
[ -f "   "]
```

Then I wrote something like this

```
[ -f "/Users/myname/Downloads/*.zip" ] && mv -f /Users/myname/Downloads/*.zip /Users/myname/Downloads/zip/ || echo 'Nothing'
```

But it returns "Nothing" even the files exist.

How can I fix this problem? Or I should not using shell command to do this?
Any suggestion?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Test whether a glob has any matches in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937407/test-whether-a-glob-has-any-matches-in-bash)

Comment: Does it actually matter that `mv` shows an error in this case? You could just ignore it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using `find` instead? Something like this:

If you can use `mv -t`

```
find /Users/myname/Downloads/ -maxdepth 1 -name "*.zip" -print0 | xargs -0 mv -f -t /Users/myname/Downloads/zip/
```

If you're unlucky (or use `-exec` as pointed out in several comments):

```
find /Users/myname/Downloads/ -maxdepth 1 -name "*.zip" -print0 | xargs -I {} -0 mv -f {} /Users/myname/Downloads/zip/
```

**EDIT** added `-print0` to make the solution white space safe.

**EDIT2** use `mv -t` instead of `{}`

Comment: You can also use `-exec` instead :)

Comment: I personally always recommend `find` over shell globbing

Comment: Better: `find /Users/mynname/Downloads/ -maxdepth 1 -name '*.zip' -exec mv {} /Users/myname/Downloads/zip/ ';'`.  Since `find` now supports `+` instead of `;`, it is often not necessary to use `xargs` with `find` — especially when the names must be processed one at a time.  GNU `mv` has an option `-t targetdir` that would allow the use of `+`; it isn't available in the native macOS `mv` command.

Comment: @PesaThe `-exec` is way inferior to `xargs`, because `xargs` reduces the number of sub-processes created. This might not matter with a few files, but does really matter when 100s or 1000s of files are involved.

Comment: @StefanBecker: The `xargs` command shown in the answer must create one process per file name — as must the `find` shown in my comment.  I extended my other comment to cover the point more thoroughly while you were adding your comment.  (The first version was brief and accurate, but not as explanatory.)

Comment: Plus `xargs` knows how to detect the maximum command line length, so the above solution will work without changes on MinGW on Windows (128K characters?) vs. Linux (2MB characters usually)

Comment: Ah yes, that's why usually avoid `{}` but always forget :-)