# tar files using for loop

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I want to archive the files above the mentioned date. I need to achieve two things,

I have sample files like this

```
ABCSMOKLO2Y_pm24hr_20180410.000006_4.csv

11randomletters_6randomalphanumeric_YYYYMMDD.randomnumbers_randomnum.csv
```

I want to tar files based on the date in the file name. Example, if I mention 10th April. Each and every date file should be tar on the specific date like this.

```
20180410.tar.gz
20180409.tar.gz
20180408.tar.gz
```

and if there is no file available on the specific date. I don't want to create a tar file for the date which has no file.

```
function archive_old_files(){

d=$(date -d"$DAYS_TO_ARCHIVE days ago" +%s)
echo "$d"
for i in {1..30}; do
    dt="$(date -d@$((d - i * 86400)) +%Y%m%d)"
    fn="$dt.tar.gz"
    if [ "$dt" -lt "$d" ] || [ -f *"$dt"* ]; then
        tar -czf "$DEST_ARCHIVE"/$fn "$SRC_DIR_ARCHIVE"/*$dt*
    fi
done
}
```

Summary :

- I need to specify the directory in the for loop. How can I achieve
- Tar all csv files above the mentioned date with file
  check(files available on specific date or not).

If there is no file available on any date. My script creates empty `date.tar.gz`.

Comment: Passing a glob, as in `[ -f *"$dt"* ]`, isn't reliable -- if you have *two* files with the substring, it expands to `[ -f 20180414-1.txt 20180414-2.txt ]`, which isn't valid syntax. See [test whether a glob has any matches in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937407/test-whether-a-glob-has-any-matches-in-bash).

Comment: Also, note that POSIX-standardized function declaration syntax is just `archive_old_files() {`, whereas legacy ksh function declaration syntax is `function archive_old_files {`; the amalgam used here is compatible with neither. See also http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete

Comment: Beyond that, though, it's just plain unclear what you mean. What would it look like to "specify the directory in the `for` loop"? Do you mean you want to iterate over directories, instead of iterate over numbers?

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

SRC_DIR_ARCHIVE=dates
DAYS_TO_ARCHIVE=30
DEST_ARCHIVE=dates/archiv

d=$(date -d"$DAYS_TO_ARCHIVE days ago" +%Y%m%d)
echo "$d"
for i in {1..30}
do
  dt="$(date -d "$d -${i} days" +%Y%m%d)"
  fn="$dt.tar.gz"
  toarc=("$SRC_DIR_ARCHIVE"/???????????_??????_${dt}.*_*.csv)
  test -f "${toarc[0]}" && \
    tar -czf "$DEST_ARCHIVE/$fn" ${toarc[*]} || \
    echo "no file, cmd: tar -czf $DEST_ARCHIVE/$fn ${toarc[*]}"
done
```

I restricted the filepattern a bit according to the possibilities of shell globbing and your description.

Then I collect the files in an array and check if the 1st element at index 0 is a file.

File/dirnames at the top are only to satisfy my testconditions.

And I didn't really understand why you calculate the date into seconds. I still don't understand why there is the variable DAYS_TO_ARCHIVE but in the loop there is `{1..30}`. Maybe because `{1..$DAYS_TO_ARCHIVE}` doesn't work, but

```
for i in $(seq 1 $DAYS_TO_ARCHIVE)
```

would work. I hope it helps you further.

If you do this for whole months and controlled by cron at the first of each month, I would consider using the date command for YYYYMM and - for 201802 for example (as for every month) just generate

```
for dt in 201802{01..31}
do 
  ...
done
```

if missing files for (nonexistent) dates get flawlessly handled.

Testing for the array size of toarc

```
 ${#toarc[0]}
```

doesn't work, because, if no file is found, the array contains the filepattern as literal text.

I hope this helps.