# How does bash treat unmatched wildcard?

Tags: bash, wildcard

I learn bash and I got the next problem using wildcards:

```
sergs:~ > ls -1
a.sh
Desktop
Downloads
eclipse
sergs:~ > a=*.sh
sergs:~ > echo $a
a.sh
sergs:~ > a=*.sha
sergs:~ > echo $a
*.sha
```

If there's no file to match a `*.sha` pattern why does `bash` return the pattern itself instead of nothing?

Thus behavior breaks such a logic:

```
for i in /usr/lib/opkg/info/*.postinst; do do_some_logic_with_postinst_file; done
```

Do I have to check that the `/usr/lib/opkg/info/` directory has no any `*.postinst` files, explicitly, before the loop or there's some other way to do it.

Comment: I'm tempted to close this as duplicate of [Test whether a glob has any matches in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2937407/5291015), but the Q needed an explanation how the unexpanded glob string is treated by the shell

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An un-expanded glob string is returned literally in the command-line unless you turn on an expanded shell option `nullglob` which returns no results if the glob expansion fails.

For your use case though, it is always a good practice to check if glob expansion is successful in a for-loop by testing it to see if the expanded result is a file i.e.

```
for file in /usr/lib/opkg/info/*.postinst; do 
    [ -f "$file" ] || continue
    do_some_logic_with_postinst_file
done
```

The condition `[ -f "$file" ]` will check if your glob expansion, i.e. if there are any `.postinst` files the `[ -f "$file" ]` would be true. For an un-expanded glob, the condition

```
[ -f /usr/lib/opkg/info/*.postinst ]
```

would fail because the literal string `/usr/lib/opkg/info/*.postinst` is not a valid file, and the failure of this `test` command along with the Boolean OR `||`  causes the `continue` action to the `for` loop. Since the `for` loop does not have any more arguments to process, the loop exits gracefully.

Doing such a way ( with the `-f` against a glob string) is guaranteed to be POSIX compliant. For a `bash` specific answer though, you can turn on the option as mentioned  before

```
# '-s' enables the option
shopt -s nullglob

for file in /usr/lib/opkg/info/*.postinst; do 
    do_some_logic_with_postinst_file
done

# '-u' disables the option
shopt -u nullglob
```

Once you decide to use the `nullglob` option, there are myriad of ways on how you can use it to run your feature. For e.g. you can put all your glob results in a an array type and check if the length is valid

```
shopt -s nullglob
results=(/usr/lib/opkg/info/*.postinst)

if (( ${#results[@]} )); then
    printf '%s\n' 'my array is not empty'
    for file in "${results[@]}"; do
        printf '%s\n' "some action on ${file}"
    done
fi

shopt -u nullglob
```

Be careful of this approach when not using the `nullglob` option. Without the same, the `results=(/usr/lib/opkg/info/*.postinst)` part could still be non-empty as the literal string is still stored in the array.

Another small addendum from your OP, is never to use variables to hold your glob string. Because when the variable is expanded unquoted and if the glob expansion is success, the contents of the variable are subject to Word-Splitting done by the shell and the filenames containing spaces could be potentially broken down to multiple entries when you expect it not to.

Always use an array and proper quoted expansion. See more on [BashFAQ - BashGuide/Arrays](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays) for an excellent read-up on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

That's how glob patterns work (edit: unless you enable `nullglob` as pointed out by Inian). Another alternative can be something like

````sh
find /usr/lib/opkg/info -name \*.postinst|while read file; do
   # do_some_logic_with_postinst_file
done```
````