# check if file exists for multiple files in different directories

Tags: bash

I am creating bash script and everything works fine except for this:

```
read -p "Write directory names:" -a dir
for f in /home/user/downloads/${dir[@]}/*.zip; do
    if [ -f $f ]; then
        #do something
    else 
        #do something else
    fi
done
```

I want to check if .zip file exists inside a directory; for multiple directories one after another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't substitute the array into the filename, you need to loop over the array.

```
read -p "Write directory names:" -a dirs
for dir in "${dirs[@]}"; do
    for f in "/home/user/downloads/$dir/"*.zip; do
        if [ -f "$f" ]
        then
            # do something
        else
            # do something else
        fi
    done
done
```

If you just want to test whether a wildcard matches anything in each directory, replace the inner loop with one of the solutions here: [Test whether a glob has any matches in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937407/test-whether-a-glob-has-any-matches-in-bash)

Comment: Generally a good answer. That said, there are some assumptions baked in here -- that `nullglob` isn't set, for one. And I'm not sure if the behavior if one of the directories contains multiple zip files (of running the "do something" block multiple times) is intended or not.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Good point. I've added a reference to a question that just shows how to check if any `.zip` files exist in the directory.