# Checking the existence of files

Tags: bash, conditional-statements

The following script checks whether FILE is in the directory.

The FILE includes 'name.pdf'

How to verify, that files name*.pdf are also in the directory?

```
if [ -f "$FILE" ]; then  # ----> how to add the condition that name*.pdf is also OK
    echo "OK $f"
else 
    echo "!!! Not OK $f"
fi
```

Comment: could you provide a sample listing of your target directory? _"..files name*.pdf are **also** in the.."_ your question seems a little unclear.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of ["Test whether a glob has any matches in bash"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937407/test-whether-a-glob-has-any-matches-in-bash) -- do the answers to that question cover what you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```sh
if [ -f name*.pdf ]; then
    echo "OK $f"
else 
    echo "!!! Not OK $f"
fi
```

**EDIT**: as stated in the comments this method won't work if more than one file match, so I've found another way:

```sh
name=name*.pdf;
if compgen -G $name > /dev/null; then
    echo "OK $f"
else 
    echo "!!! Not OK $f"
fi
```

Comment: Thank you and how to change it for name as a variable including string $name?

Comment: This does *not* work if there is more than one matching file.

Comment: Thanks and when the second `name` in  `name=name*.exe` is a variable?

Comment: @ElenaGreg I've edited my answer. Hope it can help.

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you want?

```sh
 # List the files, but stream any output to /dev/null
 # We are only interested in the exit status                   
if ls name*.pdf >/dev/null 2>&1; then 
    echo File matching pattern exist
else
    echo Files matching pattern do not exist
fi
```

This works because `if` is checking the exit status of the `ls` command. This is exactly how `if [ 'some condition' ]` works, which is a shortcut for `if test 'some condition'`: `if` is checking the exit status of `test`.  `ls` has an exit status of `0` if it finds files, otherwise it's `1` or `2` both of which `if` will evaluate as `false`.

If you want a more general solution, you can define the prefix and extension as variables:

```sh
prefix='name' #You can define the prefix and extension as variables
ext='pdf'

if $prefix*.$ext >/dev/null 2>&1; then
#the rest of the code is the same as earlier.
```

Comment: `if [ $? -eq 0 ]` is an antipattern, don't do it. Instead just do an `if`, like `if ls name*.pdf >/dev/null 2>&; then`

Comment: Good point. I did know that at one point. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score -1):

You could follow something like below

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $(find . -name "name-*.pdf") ]]; then
        echo "File Exists"
else
        echo "File Doesnt exists"
fi
```

Comment: Keep out: the `find` command automatically searches subdirectories as well. In order to avoid (or to limit) that, you might need the `-maxdepth` parameter.

Comment: Also, `name-*.pdf` needs to be quoted so the shell doesn't expand it before passing it to `find`. And you should use `find .` because some versions of `find` expect you to explicitly tell them what directory to search (I think only GNU `find` allows you to omit it).

Comment: Thanks Gordon and Dominique for your comments. I will fix it.