# bash: IF condition to remove files with a given pattern occured within subfolders

Tags: bash, loops, if-statement

As a part of my bash routine I am trying to add IF condition which should remove all csv filles contained pattern "filt" in their names:

```
# this is a folder contained all subfolders
results=./results
# looping all directories located in the $results
for d in "${results}"/*/; do
  if [ -f "${d}"/*filt*.csv ]; check if csv file is present within dir $d
   rm "${d}"/*filt*.csv # remove this csv file
  fi
done
```

Although a version without condition find and removes the csv properly:

```
rm "${d}"/*filt*.csv
```

While executing my example with IF gives the following error:

```
line 27: [: too many arguments
```

where the line 27 corresponds to the IF condition. How it could be fixed?

can I use something like without any IF statement?

```
# find all CSV filles matching pattern within the "${d}"
find "${d}" -type f -iname *filt*.csv* -delete
```

Comment: You can't do `-f` on glob patterns.

Comment: Anyway, using [tag:find] this can be simplified to something like: `find ./results -type f -iname '*filt*.csv* -delete`

Comment: Otherwise, take a look at [Test whether a glob has any matches in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937407/test-whether-a-glob-has-any-matches-in-bash).

Comment: what would be the difference between this and just rm how was shown in my working example?

Answer (score 3):

You could use `shopt -s nullglob` and then skip the test and use `rm -f "$d"/*filt*.csv` directly. The `nullglob` option makes sure that the glob not matching anything expands to the empty string, and `-f` would silence `rm`.

You could also skip the outer loop and simplify everything to

```sh
shopt -s nullglob
rm -f results/*filt*.csv
```

This *could* fail if the glob matches so many files that the maximum line length is exceeded. In that case, you're better off with `find`:

```sh
find results -name '*filt*.csv' -exec rm {} +
```

or, with GNU `find`:

```sh
find results -name '*filt*.csv' -delete
```

If there are subdirectories you want to skip, use `-maxdepth 1`. If there are directories matching the pattern, use `-type f`.