# How can I find the exist file in shell script with * argument

Tags: shell

As title,

Assume I have a file name : **test.txt** , also have another file in the directory (ex tet.txt , ttst.txt)

I want to write a script in order to not replace the content if file exist

Here is the script

```
#!/bin/bash

[[ -e /home/paul/*est.txt ]] || cat > "/home/paul/test.txt" << EOF
16
EOF
```

but I don't know why `*`(wildcard) doesn't work, it always change the content as file exists.

I also try add `''` and `""` or `$` with wildcard but doesn't work

How should I use the wildcard `*` ?

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide!!

Comment: Show us how the script is started. Note that globs are expanded -- replaced with specific file names -- _before_ the program they're passed to runs.

Comment: Beyond that, `[[` intentionally suppresses glob expansion in most contexts. This is deliberate behavior -- if it didn't, as `[` doesn't, then you'd simply have syntax errors whenever the expansion came out to the wrong number of words.

Comment: You may find [BashFAQ #4](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/004) informative.

Comment: Unclear.  You want to not replace the content if it exists?  And if it does not exist, what, create it?  Avoid double negatives, it gets confusing fast! For your `*`, the `-e` test can only work with 1 argument, not a list of files.  but that `*` can match anything.  It would be best to use `find`.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937407/test-whether-a-glob-has-any-matches-in-bash answer your question?