# Bash script that checks different folders for existence of particular type of files

Tags: bash

I have a list of folders. In every of those folders there may or may not be one or two files of a particular extension (specifically ".fastq" extension). What I want to do is write a script that enters these folders, checks if fastq file exists or not. The script I've written is below :

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Beginning operation
echo
for folder in $(ls -d */);
do
    cd ${folder%%/};
    myfolder=${folder::-1}
    echo
    echo Entered $myfolder

    fastq_test=(´find ./ -maxdepth 1 -name "*.fastq"´)
    if [ ${#fastq_test[@]} -gt 0 ];
    then
        echo There are FASTQ files, will not do the operation
    else
        echo There are no FASTQ files, proceeding with operation
        #operation here
    fi
    cd ..
    echo Exited $myfolder
    echo 
done
echo Ended Operation
```

My problem is that this script doesn't work - it finds FASTQ files in folders that do not have them. Is there any better way?

Comment: Check your scripts with shellcheck.net . See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937407/test-whether-a-glob-has-any-matches-in-bash

Comment: Those non-standard quotes `´` are not syntactically valid, it looks like you are trying to use backticks (which you also should not use here, [for several reasons](https://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#backtick)) but you are simply examining whether the literal string `´find ./ -maxdepth 1 -name "*.fastq"´` is nonempty, which is of course it is (though that is a painful way to test it; simply `if [ "string" ]` does the same thing).

Comment: ivan199415, @KamilCuk, I updated my answer. The question was a bit more complex than just `Test whether a glob has any matches in Bash`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In bash you can do:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

for dir in ./*/
do
    if compgen -G "$dir*.fastq" > /dev/null
    then
        echo 'There are FASTQ files, will not do the operation'
    elif pushd "$dir" > /dev/null
    then
        echo 'There are no FASTQ files, proceeding with operation'
        # operations...
        popd > /dev/null
    fi
done
```

---

###### notes:

- The trailing slash in `./*/` makes it so that the `glob` only matches directories, and the `./` at the start is a ***safety*** against names that start with dash.
- `compgen -G 'glob'` is a great bash way for testing the existence of files/directories that match a `glob`. That said, its output isn't worth anything in your case (and in general when used for glob matching, because you'll need the `/./` | `././` trick for detecting newlines in a file/dir name).
- `pushd` will `cd` you to `"$dir"`; then you use `popd` to return to the previous directory. `pushd` `popd` are useful but their output is annoying.

Comment: Wonderful solution, and thanks for all the notes. Everything works, all I need to do now is input the operation. Thanks.