# Bash compgen not parsing wildcard correctly

Tags: bash, wildcard, glob, compgen

My goal is to list all files matching `foo/**` whereas this folder contains files (1 and 2) and subdirectories (bar) with files:

```
foo/
├── 1
└── bar
    └── 2
```

Bash has a build-in called `compgen`. I found out about this function [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937407/test-whether-a-glob-has-any-matches-in-bash). Using `compgen -G <pattern>`, in my case `compgen -G 'foo/**'` should list all files and folders. However, it only prints out the contents of the first folder (foo):

```
foo/bar
foo/1
```

-> `foo/bar/2` is missing! I'd expect the following output:

```
foo/bar
foo/1
foo/bar/2
```

**Is this a bug in bash's compgen or is the glob incorrect?**

---

### More experiments

```
$ compgen -G 'foo/**/*'
foo/bar/2
```

---

Using Python3's pathlib.Path.glob:

```
from pathlib import Path
p=Path(".").resolve()
[print(f) for f in p.glob("foo/**")]
```

Output:

```
foo
foo/bar
```

---

```
from pathlib import Path
p=Path(".").resolve()
[print(f) for f in p.glob("foo/**/*")]
```

Output:

```
foo/1
foo/bar
foo/bar/2
```

This version does exactly what I want, however, I'd prefer to minimize dependencies and not use Python at all (bash only).

---

- Bash version 5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) on Ubuntu 20.04.
- Bash globstar option on/off doesn't change anything
- Python 3.6.9

Comment: Is the `globstar` shell option active? `**` only has any special meaning when that flag (which is off-by-default for POSIX compliance) is set.

Comment: Beyond that, are you interested in answers on how to expand this _without_ using compgen? `printf '%q\n' foo/**` is pretty simple, and if your goal is to file a bug report rather than to find a solution to a practical problem, this is the wrong place to do it (the right place being the bash-bug mailing list).

Comment: Enabling or disabling globstar doesn't change anything.

Comment: To expand on my assertion that compgen is the wrong tool for the job (as a general rule): Because it's generating autocompletions to be added to a command line, its content needs to be escaped as shell syntax. In almost every case, that's less appropriate or correct than literal data -- bash doesn't provide good tools for parsing shell syntax back to data without `eval`, and using `eval` involves security risks; and if you _do_ want to transform data into a form where it can be parsed as shell syntax, bash provides several ways to do that after generation is complete.

Comment: ...a few of those: `printf '%q ' "${array[@]}"`, `array_str="${array[*]@Q}"`, etc. And to serialize your data in a form that's both unambiguous and trivial to deserialize in any other language, `printf '%s\0' "${array[@]}"` to generate NUL-delimited data works correctly with all possible filenames -- which newline-delimited streams _do not_, as newlines are valid in filenames on widespread systems (including Linux w/ ext4/btrfs/other major filesystems).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`compgen` is a tool that exists specifically for generating completions. It *does* appear to be buggy (insofar as it doesn't honor the `globstar` option), but it's also not the best tool to use to generate a list of files matching a glob; so there's no real practical reason for that bug to be one anyone cares about.

The best tool is, well, a glob expression.

```
shopt -s extglob nullglob
files=( foo/** ) # store files matching foo/** in an array
echo "Found ${#files[@]} files:"
printf ' - %q\n' "${files[@]}"
```

If in your real-world environment you want to get the glob expression to expand from a variable, and *only* perform globbing and suppress string-splitting, then you'd want to temporarily set `IFS` to an empty value while performing the `files=( $glob )` assignment.

Comment: You're right. A simple glob + globstar does the trick. I think compgen doesn't honor the globstar setting.