If file with different extension is missing
This seems simple but I haven't been able to modify my script to make it work (attempts are commented out).
This is a script that searches for raw files, and if there's no associated jpg file, it does something (to produce a corresponding jpg, but that's not the issue here). The script below works fine for that.
The problem is that file.raw can have an associated file.jpg, but also sometimes file.something.jpg, which... I haven't been able to add to shoehorn in the script.
#! /bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob       # Avoid *.something result in for loop

for File in *.{rw2,raf,raw,dng,nef,cr2,new,orf}
do
#       if compgen -G "${File%.*}"*jpg > /dev/null
#       find . -maxdepth 1 -name "${File%.*}*jpg"
#       if test -n "$(find . -maxdepth 1 -name '${File%.*}*jpg' -print -quit)"

        if [ ! -f "${File%.*}.jpg" ];
        then
                # Do something
        fi
done

So in summary:

if file.raw and no file*.jpg -> do something
if file.raw and any file*.jpg -> do nothing
I think the nullglob necessary for the for loop breaks things up for the other wildcards...


file.jpg, but also sometimes file.something.jpg What about something.file.jpg? What about filesomething.jpg? What about if there are two files file.1.jpg or file.2.jpg? What are the exact rules of associated jpg file name with raw file? And as for if file.raw and no file*.jpg -> do something See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937407/test-whether-a-glob-has-any-matches-in-bash and do if ! compgen -G "${File%.*}*.jpg" >/dev/null; then echo no matches; fi

exactly, what is something.file.something.jpg exists?

As I stated in the end, any file*.jpg is okay, so something.file.something.jpg is out.

You can't use -f on a wildcard if it could match more than one file; and you can't put the wildcard inside quotes, because that protects it from the shell.
#! /bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob       # Avoid *.something result in for loop

for File in *.{rw2,raf,raw,dng,nef,cr2,new,orf}
do
    files=("${File%.*}"*".jpg")
    if [[ ! -f "${files[0]}" ]]
    then
        # Do something
    fi
done


I knew about not quoting the wildcard but didn't think about using an array to store the results. Thanks, that works

another way of doing things would be (without shopt -s nullglob):
#!/bin/bash

extensions=(./*.rw2 ./*.raf ./*.raw ./*.dng ./*.nef ./*.cr2 ./*.new ./*.orf)

for file in "${extensions[@]}"; do
    [ -e "$file" ] || continue  # test whether there is a matching file

    if [ ! -f "${file%.*}"*.jpg ]; then
        # Do something :)
        echo "$file" # echoing just for testing
    fi
done

